# deluxetable error (Illegal pream-token (\string): 'c' used \startdata) when using \rowcolor and \specialcell

Tags: tables, colortbl, aastex

I'm having an issue with `deluxetable` and am given the following errors:

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\string): 'c' used \startdata
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\string): 'c' used \startdata
```

I should note that, while I am given these errors, the table *is* generated.  However, the errors are annoying and I would like to figure out why they are occurring.

#### A little about this table

I am grouping dates with events but there can be more than one event for a given date.  Additionally, some dates are grouped together.  I am using `\rowcolor` to color different groupings of dates.  Given the carriage returns needed for events, I'm defining a new command called `\specialcell` to generate carriage returns. A copy of the table is shown below.

I know the error is associated with `\rowcolor` and `\specialcell` but I require both for the table. Additionally, the table is too long and, instead of breaking and starting on a new page, I'm forced to use `\tablebreak` which causes me to have the second preamble error.

The text of the code is written below.

#### main.tex packages

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint]{aastex-thesis}

\usepackage{epsfig}  
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{endfloat} 
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
 \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\textdegree}{${}^\circ$}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\input{Thesis_chp2_groundbased_obs}

\end{document}
```

#### Thesis_chp2_groundbased_obs.tex that includes table

```
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\begin{deluxetable}{ccccccccccc}

  \rotate
  \tablewidth{0pt}
  \tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
  \tablecaption{Current Study Green Line Observations from Apache Point Observatory}
  \tablecolumns{11}
  \tablehead{& & && \multicolumn{3}{c}{5577.3 \AA{} Intensity} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Solar Activity} \\ UT Date & Time & Velocity && Earth & Venus & Venus/Earth && Flare & Date & CME/ \\ MM/DD/YY & & km/s && (R) & (R) &&& (Lead/Trail) & MM/DD (Time) & CIR}

 \startdata  %<---- where the error occurs
 \input{table_APO_obs.tex}
 \enddata
  \label{tab1}
\end{deluxetable}
```

#### table_APO_obs.tex data

```
$^1$12/21/10 & 11:30 - 13:30 &  13.1 && -- & -- & -- && -- & -- & -- \\
\rowcolor{Gray}
$^1$12/27/10 & 11:30 - 13:30 & -13.1 && -- & -- & Weak (32\%) && -- & -- & CIR \\
$^1$04/17/12 & 02:00 - 04:00 & -13.0 && -- & -- & -- && M 1.7 (T 62\textdegree) & 04/16 (17:45) & -- \\
\rowcolor{Gray}
$^1$04/18/12 & 02:00 - 04:00 & -12.0 && -- & -- & Weak (15\%) && M 1.0 (L 56\textdegree) & 04/27  (08:15) & CME \\
$^1$04/22/12 & 02:00 - 04:00 & -11.3 && -- & -- & -- &&\specialcell{M 1.4 (T 65\textdegree) \\M 1.3 (T 55\textdegree)} & \specialcell{05/05 (13:39)\\05/05 (22:56} & \\
\rowcolor{Gray}
$^1$07/14/12 & 10:30 - 12:00 & 12.7 && -- & -- & Strong (130\%) && \specialcell{X 1.4 (T 08\textdegree)\\M 1.0 (T 59\textdegree)} & \specialcell{07/12 (15:37)\\07/14 (04:51)} & CME \\
\rowcolor{Gray}
$^1$07/15/12 & 10:30 - 12:00 & 12.8 && -- & -- & Medium (50\%) && & &\\
\rowcolor{Gray}
$^1$07/16/12 & 10:30 - 12:00 & 12.9 && -- & -- & Medium (63\%) && & & \\
```

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `deluxetable` (and thus `aastex` and derivatives) is incompatible with `colortbl`:

```
\documentclass{aastex}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{deluxetable}{ll}
  \tablehead{ab}
  \startdata
    1 & 2
  \enddata
\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

You simply can't use the two together, I'm afraid.